# Variable in View is always nil

Tags: ruby, variables, view, controller, null

I am new to ruby. I created a new action in controller where I set variable test1

```
def tsload
   @test1 = '00:00'
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html {
        render :template => 'tsload'
     }
   end
end
```

But in my View the value of variable test1 is always nil. It seems that it is undefined.

```
<p>Test</p>
<% if @test1.nil? %>
<p>nil</p>
<% end %>
```

I do not understand what is wrong. In older actions in my controller everything works OK. Can anyone please help me?
This is line from my routes.rb

```
match 'wktime/tsload', :to => 'wktime#tsload', :via => [:get]
```

Comment: What's the name of the controller, controller file, and the view file?

Comment: controller file: wktime_controller.rb controller name: wktime view file: tsload.html.erb